# index() Method Not Accepting None as Start/Stop

Tags: python, python-3.x

While writing a binary search method for a list I decided to use the builtin `index()` method on a smaller slice of the list determined via the binary search method. However in certain cases I was getting the error:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

This occurred whenever the list was below a certain length. The code that caused it was:

```
def iter_chop(target, a_list):
    arr = a_list[:]
    start = None
    stop = None
    <snip>
    return a_list.index(target, start, stop)
```

Where `start` and `stop` where both `None`.

The error message indicates that `None` is an acceptable parameter and it should be as this is valid Python:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a[None:None]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So I had assumed calling `a.index(3, None,  None)` would be equivalent to calling `a[None:None].index(3)`. However:

```
>>> a.index(3,None,None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#199>", line 1, in <module>
    a.index(3,None,None)
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Did I wrongly assume how the parameters for `index()` are treated despite what the error message indicates? Is this a bug?

Comment: Hrm, the documentation does give the *impression* that `None` could work because they state it is *roughly equivalent to using `s[i:j].index(x)`*. It's a documentation bug in that case.

Comment: _"The error message indicates that None is an acceptable parameter"_. I don't think it does, actually. I think the source code for `index` contains another function which is raising that error. So it's that internal function that can take integers or None, rather than `index` itself. (I agree with Martijn that the docs are somewhat misleading, in any case)

Comment: You get the same exact error message if you try to do this `[1,2,3][0:'s']` so I'm under the possibly naive assumption that there is some slicing going on under the hood.

Comment: @Kevin: indeed, the error message comes from [`_PyEval_SliceIndex`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3ded282f9615/Python/ceval.c#l4571), which assumes that the caller has already tested for `None`. But the [calling code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3ded282f9615/Objects/listobject.c#l2147) does no such thing. It does not support `None`.

Comment: @IanAuld: a utility function for slicing is being used, it is just not the exact same thing as slicing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug with how the arguments are being parsed. See [issue #1259](https://bugs.python.org/issue1259) and [issue #11828](https://bugs.python.org/issue11828) for the same bug with *string methods*, and [issue #13340](https://bugs.python.org/issue13340) for lists.

Yes, the documentation implies that the indices are used in *roughly* the same way as a slice, and the internal utility function used to parse those arguments gives a misleading error message.

The list bug appears to be hung up on a change in the API and what versions would get the fix, or alternatively, if the error message should be fixed instead.

Comment: Did they mention what color they will be painting the bike shed?